# How do you add a button to a tableview so that it extracts user data specific to the cell in which it was pushed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my project thus far, I have successfully implemented a tableview whose cells populate postings from FIR database.

I can't figure out what code to add so that when the message user button is pushed, the poster's userID specific to that cell is identified and extracted. If I could get that far, I can extract the rest of the other user's info so that I can set up a chat that includes the receiver of the message's userID, userFirstName, and profile pic.

I would guess that tagging the button is a first step, but I'm not sure how that gets me the userID specific to that posting.

I don't even have code to show because I'm clueless in how to do this....

Comment: I need to add this to the cell for row path:

Comment: cell.messageButton.tag = indexPath.row

Comment: I needed to add this to my cell class:

Comment: @IBAction func messageButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            let messageButton = sender as! UIButton
            let object = filteredPosts[(messageButton.tag)]
            otherUID = object.uId

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put this since it doesn't format code and I don't think I'm supposed to touch the answer section.

Comment: Please update your question with relevant information. Also, it does offer a code block using the {} option - if you copy and paste from Xcode, select that  code and hit {} it will more or less look correct and be readable.

Comment: Typically your tableView is populated from a dataSource - often times an array. When a row (cell) is clicked in the tableView, that corresponds to an index in the dataSource array which contains the data you need. The delegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is helpful. There are a LOT of guides on tableView programming so those would be a good reference to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Put the button in cell. Also make a custom class of cell and put the userId or user object in that cell. When you tap the button you can get the userId etc from that cell.
Or if you want to get that event from cell to viewcontroller you can pass delegate to view viewcontroller. Some thing like this

```
//cellforrowatindexpath
cell.delegate = self
cell.indexPath = indexPath 

// Your cell class
protocol CellDelegate: class {
  func didTapCell(index: IndexPath)
}

 @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.delegate?.didTapCell(index: indexPath)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//tag the cell button        
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HealerProfileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! yourTVCell

            cell.detailsButton.tag = indexPath.row

            cell.detailsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HealersTableViewController.performHealerDetailsInfoSegue(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            return cell
        }

//make a function

        func performHealerDetailsInfoSegue(sender: AnyObject?) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("your segue identifier", sender: sender)
        }

//use prepare for segue method

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            let object = yourArray[(sender!.tag)]

            if segue.identifier == "your segue identifier" {
                let dvc =  segue.destinationViewController as! YourVC
                dvc.object = object
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. Yeah, I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a target to your button in the `TableView cellForItemAtIndexPath` Method.

```
cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CellButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Then add this function that is called when the button is pushed...

```
func CellButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Clicked")

    guard let cellInAction = sender.superview as? YourCell else { return }
    guard let din = yourTableView?.indexPath(for: cellInAction) else { return }

// retrieve the specific values in the cell from your array
    let specificCellData = yourArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
}
```